# Azure App or Delegated permission to write in user's calendar

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

My web app authenticates the user through the Azure sso and then uses the generated access
token to retrieve some user infos and generate a new access token that belongs to my application that allows the user to call web app apis, the azure token is then thrown away.

Later on the user could use a specific feature of the web app that involves calling an api of the application that access the user's outlook calendar and creates a new event for a specified date and time.

To do this i configured the Azure service principle with the Calendar.Write permission set as app permission and then I call the azure graph api authenticating with client and secret of the app from the web app api.
This way the rest api does not depend on the user access token given by the Azure login flow that could expire anytime but makes it's own calls.

I'm wondering if this is the right approach or should I set the Calendar.Write permission as delegated and then ask for the user access token as an api parameter to make the graph api call in the implementation.
But this way if the azure token is expired the user must re-enter credentials before using the feature.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think either approach is "wrong"; they have pros and cons. App permissions are more reliable and simpler but might give too much access or be undesirable in a SaaS application. Delegated permissions give granular access and allow per-user consent, but are less reliable and require more work for implementation. We implemented a similar thing with delegated permissions. We had a background job that refreshes the cached refresh tokens at an interval and used those cached tokens for the integrations.

Comment: So you had to store the access token and refresh token in a database?

Comment: We used Azure Key Vault specifically to store the refresh tokens. We acquired access tokens using the refresh tokens as needed, which was not often in this case. We did calendar sync in the background.